# Solving 50! mod 103

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to solve 50! mod 103?
Please give me a hint.
I have searched about various theorems but could not find solution.

Comment: Have you considered separating out some of the terms of $50!$ that multiply together to be equal to $1 \mod 103$?  If you can cross a couple of those off the list, then the remaining set will be less than $50$ terms, and modular arithmetic base $103$ isn't too difficult.

Comment: Hint: What is $102!$ mod $103$?  Then knowing this, how does this help you?  My thought is a variant on Gauss' trick.

Comment: This is Wilson Theorem!

Comment: Note that $103 \equiv 3 \mod 4$ so Wilson's Theorem and associated suggestions get us to $(51!)^2\equiv 1$ but we need something more to know which of $51!\equiv \pm1$ actually holds before we can make more progress.

Comment: The fact that this might not be wholly easy is indicated by the discussion here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16141/primes-p-such-that-p-1-2-1-mod-p, which involves the class number of the quadratic field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-103})$ - it took less time to do the calculation using the mod function on a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

$50!=1\times2\times3\times\cdots\times48\times49\times50$

Note $103$ is prime hence $\varphi(103)=102$ and therefore $a^{102}\equiv1\mod103$ for $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ that are not multiples of $103$. This may help you reduce the product somewhat.

Comment: I guess that should be for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathrm{gcd}(a, 103) = 1$ :)

Comment: @AlexandreVandermonde fair point, I think I meant to add $a\in\mathbb{Z},a<50$ specifically here

Answer (score 2):

First notice that $103$ is a prime. Consider now the integers $1, 2, 3, ... \frac{103-1}{2}=51, \frac{103 + 1}{2}=52, ..., 102$. These are all the integers less than $103$. Can you see if they relate to each other nicely parewise $(\mathrm{mod} \ 103)$? If you can, form their product and equate it to 
$102! \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 103)$. Now use Wilson's theorem, and you should be able to find a nice result.

EDIT:
You will find $(51!)^2 \equiv 1 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 103)$. As pointed out above, this, unfortunately, does not fully answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

This can be computed in [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) using:

```
Factorial(50) mod 103;
```

which returns `2`.

---

As far as I can tell, none of the earlier proposed methods will succeed (please correct me if I'm missing something).

- We compute $$50!=2^{47} \cdot 3^{22} \cdot 5^{12} \cdot 7^8 \cdot 11^4 \cdot 13^3 \cdot 17^2 \cdot 19^2 \cdot 23^2 \cdot 29 \cdot 31 \cdot 37 \cdot 41 \cdot 43 \cdot 47$$ where each exponent is less than $\varphi(103)$, so [Euler's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) cannot be applied to simplify things.
- In the [Wilson's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) approach, we obtain a square, which means we can only reduce the problem down to one of two possibilities, namely $\pm 2$, but which is it?

Comment: See my comment on the question with a link to the Mathoverflow discussion - which does provide an answer to "which is it?" - but not an easy answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can use Wilson Theorem and we know $102!\equiv -1 \mod103$ and $102!\equiv -(51!)^2 \mod103$ and therefore $1 \equiv 26\times (50!)^2 \mod103$. We can have   $4 \equiv  (50!)^2 \mod103$ which is:
$$
\pm 2 \equiv  50! \mod 103.
$$
However this cannot go further.

Answer (score 0):

As it was pointed before  $51! \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{103}$.

As $\left( \frac{1}{103} \right)=1$ and $\left( \frac{-1}{103} \right)=-1$ all we need to do is calculate the Legendre symbol

$$\left( \frac{51!}{103} \right)$$

Using the factorization

$$51!=2^{47} \cdot 3^{23} \cdot 5^{12} \cdot 7^8 \cdot 11^4 \cdot 13^3 \cdot 17^3 \cdot 19^2 \cdot 23^2 \cdot 29 \cdot 31 \cdot 37 \cdot 41 \cdot 43 \cdot 47$$ and getting rid of perfect squares we get

$$\left( \frac{51!}{103} \right)=\left( \frac{2 \cdot 3  \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 29 \cdot 31 \cdot 37 \cdot 41 \cdot 43 \cdot 47}{103} \right)$$

Now we start symplyfying:

$$\left( \frac{2   \cdot 13 \cdot 17 }{103} \right)\left( \frac{3   \cdot 47 }{103} \right)\left( \frac{29   \cdot 43 }{103} \right)\left( \frac{31   \cdot 41 }{103} \right)\left( \frac{37 }{103} \right)=$$
$$\left( \frac{30 }{103} \right)\left( \frac{38 }{103} \right)\left( \frac{11}{103} \right)\left( \frac{35}{103} \right)\left( \frac{37 }{103} \right)=\left( \frac{2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 19 \cdot 37 }{103} \right)=\left( \frac{ 3  \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 19 \cdot 37 }{103} \right)$$
$$\left( \frac{ 3 \cdot 37 }{103} \right)\left( \frac{  7  \cdot 19  }{103} \right)\left( \frac{ 11  }{103} \right)=\left( \frac{8}{103} \right)\left( \frac{  30  }{103} \right)\left( \frac{ 11  }{103} \right)=\left( \frac{ 2^4 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 11  }{103} \right)=\left( \frac{  3 \cdot 5 \cdot 11  }{103} \right)$$
$$=\left( \frac{  2  }{103} \right)\left( \frac{  31  }{103} \right)=1 \cdot (-1)\left( \frac{  103  }{31} \right)=-\left( \frac{  2 }{31} \right)\left( \frac{  5  }{31} \right)=-1 \cdot\left( \frac{  36  }{31} \right)=-1$$

This proves that

$$50!(51) \equiv -1 \pmod{103}$$

Multiplying by $2$ we get

$$50!(-1) \equiv -2 \pmod{103}$$

**P.S. ** As I did the computations by hand, it would surprise me if there is no mistake in them. Also, the computations can probably be simplified a lot by grouping the terms the right way.